# D3 text properties

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am creating a dynamic bar chart, the dataset array will vary. I need to set the text label property to adjust to the rect bar as the dataset changes. Can anyone help me to figure it out..fiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/xtgbhdw8/3/

```
svg.selectAll(".bar-label")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("text")
            .classed("bar-label", true)
            .attr("x", function(d,i){
                return x(d.type) ;
                })
           .attr("dx", 50)
           .attr("dy", ".85em")
           .attr("y", function(d,i){
                return y(d.amount);
            })
            .text(function(d,i){
                return d.amount;
            })
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem in the jsfiddle, if you add other objects in the dataset the text follows the bars accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/xtgbhdw8/5/

Comment: thanks @tomotomtom but the position or padding of the text will not align properly. Try to delete 4 of the objects in the array and observe the text position

Comment: you need to set the x position of the text elements using rangeroundbands, like explained here: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/02/making-bar-chart-in-d3js.html or here: http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/making-a-bar-chart where he's using a different approach. anyway I'd suggest you to use rangeroundbands